# Tab size and indent size

Tags: tabs, editor, text-editor

In the configuration of text editors I notice the following settings: tab size and indent size (which both are usually set to 2 or 4). What is the difference between them?

Comment: Probably the best setting is 2 and 4.

Answer (score 5):

Tab size is the amount of whitespaces that will be visually displayed where the "tab" character is encountered. The indent size - is how many whitespaces will be put in the indented line start. Sometimes it is done with tabs, sometimes with spaces, depending on configuration.

Comment: This answer can be improved even with images. It is not straight forward clear what's the difference between "tab size" and "indent size".